# I am having trouble overloading operator* in a templated vector class

Tags: c++

This is my operator overload for multiplying a vector by an int:

```
template <typename T>
int& vector<T>::operator*(const int& b) {
    int ans = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < this->size(); i++) {
        ans += this[i] * b;
    }
    return ans;
}
```

This is my overload for vector*vector that should return dot product:

```
template <typename T>
int vector<T>::operator*(const vector<T>& b) const {
    int t = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++)
        t += (this[i] * b[i]);
    return t;
}
```

No matter how I have defined or declared it, I get an error

> No operator "*" matches these operands
>   operand types are: int * PIC10b::vector<int>

`PIC10b` is the name of the namespace I've written to contain my vector.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I also recommend you check out [this canonical binary arithmetic canonical implementation reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Binary_arithmetic_operators). Your return type is from, to begin with.

Comment: You made this a template on `T`, but you're assuming that the vector holds `int`.

Comment: That operator will only work for `PIC10b::vector * int` and not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't understand the first block of code because you're trying to return an int when the function says it will return a reference to an int.

```
int vector<T>::operator*(const int& b) {
```